# How does Python 3.x deal with indeterminate forms such as 0/0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculus

So just as the question states, I'm wondering how python calculates equations such as

```
def indeterminate(x):
    return (x - math.sin(x)) / math.pow(x, 3)
```

where Limit approaches 0. I'm asking because when I input

```
>>> indeterminate(0.0000001)
0.17205356741102978
```

Where as

```
>>> indeterminate(0.00000001)
0.0
```

Shouldn't the output be approaching 1/6? And if it becomes too close, wouldn't a ZeroDivisionError message be more suitable than 0.0?

Another question I have is how do I calculate the actual number of

```
indeterminate(0.00000001)
```

The correct answer using L'hopital's rule should be 1/6 but (0.166666...) and not 0.1720...

Comment: I just realised that

    '''indeterminate(0.00001)'''

is more accurate than if I were to put more zeros. Could someone kindly explain to me as well? Thanks!

Comment: Here is 1 type of example of how limited precision for the representation of floating point numbers in computers can cause artifacts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: If you are expecting an "actual number", then you are completely misunderstanding what floating-point numbers *are*.  The only value in your code that has an exact representation as a float is that 3.

Comment: If you need perfect precision, consider using a library for that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: In general, CPython is at the mercy of the underlying floating point implementation of whatever system is it is running on

Comment: @sshashank124: `decimal` isn't exact either. It's just configurable-precision, and decimal. It won't prevent rounding error.

Comment: [Python arbitrary precision library](http://mpmath.org/) using 50 digits returns 0.16666666666666658333333333333336071657591591300437 as desired.  Using mpmath for your formula is simple: formula becomes `return (x - mp.sin(x)) /mp.power(x, 3)` which means using mpmath sine and power functions rather than math.